# problem getting my program to work

Tags: c

I'm having a novice problem with my program here....

I want it to print a list of cities in both ascending and descending order, so far i'm only getting the descending part implemented.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(void) {
  int i, j, ch, sort=0;
  printf("HOW WOULD YOU LIKE TO SORT?\n\nASCENDING\n\nDESCENDING\n\n");
  ch=getc(stdin);
  if(toupper(ch)=='A'&&tolower(ch)=='a') sort=1;
  if(sort==1) printf("\nSORT ASCENDING...\n");
  else printf("\nSORT DESCENDING...\n");
  printf("\nHOW MANY CITIES WOULD YOU LIKE? : - \n");
  scanf("%d",&i);
  char NAMES[i][20];
  j=0;
  while(j<i) {
    printf("ENTER NAME ");
    scanf("%s",NAMES[j]);
    j++;
  }
  char swapNAME[20];
  int r,k;
  printf("THE ORIGINAL LIST WAS :\n");
  for(r=0;r<i;r++) printf("%s\n",NAMES[r]);
  for(r=0;r<i-1;r++) {
    for(k=r+1;k<i;k++) {
      if(strcmp(NAMES[k],NAMES[r])>0) {
         strcpy(swapNAME,NAMES[r]);
         strcpy(NAMES[r],NAMES[k]);
         strcpy(NAMES[k],swapNAME);
      }
    }
  }
  printf("\n THE SORTED LIST IS NOW : \n");
  for(r=0;r<i;r++) printf("%s\n",NAMES[r]);
  getc(stdin);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

please any efforts made will greatly be appreciated aganin thankz

Comment: What is the exact problem?  Are you getting an error?  On which line of code?

Comment: An aesthetic and moot point, but do you really need to print in all caps?

Answer (score 2):

If the descending sort is working, then all you need is an extra condition in the `if` statement to handle the other direction:

```
 for(r=0;r<i-1;r++) {
    for(k=r+1;k<i;k++) {
      if((sort==0 && strcmp(NAMES[k],NAMES[r])>0)||
         (sort==1 && strcmp(NAMES[k],NAMES[r])<0)) {
         strcpy(swapNAME,NAMES[r]);
         strcpy(NAMES[r],NAMES[k]);
         strcpy(NAMES[k],swapNAME);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your sorting is off.  To fix that problem, just replace your bubble sort with a call to qsort, and that immediately leads to a good way to do your reverse sorting.  In particular, try:

```
int
rstrcmp( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    return -strcmp( s1, s2 );
}


int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    ...
    int (*compare)(const char *s1, const char *s2 );
    /* Based on user input, set 
    compare = rstrcmp;
    -- or --
    compare = strcmp;
    */
    ...
    qsort( NAMES, i, 20, compare );
    ...
```

As a recommendation, do not prompt for the sort direction but let the user pass it as a flag in argv.